# Is there test of normality in the gtsummary package?

Tags: gtsummary

Want to confirm that gtsummary does not test the continuous variables to see if the data is normally-distributed. It seems like it always shows the median (IQR) and conduct non-normal comparison tests by default? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: The default is to present median IQR in `tbl_summary()` and rank-sum test in `add_p()` for continuous variables. This is documented in the respective help files. The defaults statistics can be updated of course (examples in the help files)

Comment: Check out `theme_gtsummary_mean_sd()` if you want means, SDs, t-test, etc. by default. http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/theme_gtsummary.html